# Simple way to work with the Ansi and the Unicode version of a Windows API structure in C#/VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, winapi, unicode, interop

For interop reasons I need to work with both the ANSI and the Unicode version of the some Windows API structure ([DEVMODE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183565.aspx)).

Is there a way to do that without declaring everything *twice*? Currently, my structs are defined like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
struct DevModeAnsi
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string dmDeviceName;
    public Int16 dmSpecVersion;
    // ... lots of other fields ...
    public Int16 dmOrientation;
    // ... lots of other fields ...
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
struct DevModeUnicode
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string dmDeviceName;
    public Int16 dmSpecVersion;
    // ... lots of other fields ...
    public Int16 dmOrientation;
    // ... lots of other fields ...
}
```

and, worse, I need to duplicate all my code as well:

```
bool IsLandscapeOrientation(DevModeAnsi d) { return d.dmOrientation == DMORIENT_LANDSCAPE; }
bool IsLandscapeOrientation(DevModeUnicode d) { return d.dmOrientation == DMORIENT_LANDSCAPE; }
```

I have considered the following solutions:

- Make a common base struct: Won't work, since structs don't support inheritance.
- Use a common interface: Won't work, since interfaces cannot contain fields, only properties. Thus, I'd have to create a property for *every single field* I want to access, *quadrupling* the list of fields instead of simply doubling it.
- T4: Last resort, but I'd rather avoid that that extra layer of complexity, if possible.

Is there an elegant solution that I've missed?

Comment: *Is there a way to do that without declaring everything twice?* No. *Is there an elegant solution that I've missed?* No.

Comment: Well, sure, there is no conceivable reason to still use CharSet.Ansi.  The floppy disk drive on the last Windows ME machine failed 5 years ago, it only lives on in infamy.  Avoid an XY question please.

Comment: @HansPassant: Tell that to Microsoft: Serializing an MS Access 2007 report to a text file with `SaveAsText` saves the printer settings as an ANSI(!) DEVMODE structure. In other words: Yes, I do have an actual legacy system returning an ANSI DEVMODE structure.

Comment: A text file with a binary DEVMODE sounds too far-fetched.  Surely the real problem is the encoding that your StreamReader uses.  You will not like the default, use Encoding.Default instead.

Comment: @HansPassant: Yes, it actually *is* a text file with a binary DEVMODE structure, those files look like this: https://svn.access-codelib.net/svn/codelib/branches/draft/api/PdfCreator/PdfCreatorExample.frm

Comment: @HansPassant: And it's not just Access 2007, also the current Access 2016. I'm actually a bit disappointed that you think a 90k user with a C# gold badge would be too stupid to properly use a StreamReader...

Comment: You have one structure that you want to deal with. Hardly a big job to do it twice.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: No, not a big job; I just wanted to know if the redundancy can be avoided, and your first comment answered this perfectly. If you make that an answer, I'll accept it (it seems simple for an answer, but sometimes there really isn't much more to say).

Comment: I learned something new, it was worth pulling the teeth.  If you can't pinvoke the corresponding ansi versions of the winapi functions that use DEVMODEA then you'll have to slug it out.  Do watch out for the printer driver-specific data appended at the end, you'll have a hard time translating it.

Comment: @HansPassant: Fortunately, at the moment, I don't need the driver-specific data and only need to read/write it from/to text files (no P/Invoke).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to do that without declaring everything twice?

No.

> Is there an elegant solution that I've missed?

No.

You could write your own marshalling code to serialize such structs with the added flexibility that you desire. But the effort involved would far outweigh the benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a template which would receive the structure name and would contain the field declarations. A folder would be mapped to the template. Whenever a given executable mapped to this feature would be executed, it would generate the files as output. The folder would be added to an autoloader and the executable would support the following commands:

- addfield
- mofidyfield
- removefield
- addstructure
- removestructure